# Converting Matlab function to Python

Tags: python, function, matlab

I have a Matlab file that I'm looking to convert into Python. Part of it is functions and I'm a bit confused by it. In the Matlab code, there is a function that looks like this:

```matlab
function [u, v, speed, dir] = NewCalculations(data)
```

Would the Python equivalent of this be?:

```py
def NewCalculations(data):
    u = data.u
    v = data.v
    speed = data.speed
    dir = data.dir
```

I have read up on Matlab functions, but am still confused by the syntax and how it could be rewritten into Python. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be like this:

```
def NewCalculations(data):
# some calculations
    return u, v, speed, dir
```

The matlab syntax is

```
function outvars = functionname(inputvars)
```

Comment: Ah, gotcha, ok. So anything on the left hand side of the equal sign in Matlab would be the returned variables then in a Python function, if I'm understanding correctly?